# name of uploaded file in title field

Tags: javascript

I have seen on youtube when we upload any videos automatically, the title field of form gets filled with the name of the video file. How can i achieve this?

my form is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://youshare.ca/music/writestorypost"><p>
    <span class="form_label">Title</span><input type="text" value="" name="title" style="width:400px" class="inputText required"></p>
    <p><label>Upload</label><input type="file" name="song">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></p><input type="hidden" value="935" name="page_id">
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: please paste the code whatever you tried..

Comment: i dont have any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some jquery code to make it work:

```
$('#myfile').change( function(){
    var fileValue = $(this).val();
    $('#mytitle').val(fileValue);
});
```

And here's the modified HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://youshare.ca/music/writestorypost"><p>
    <span class="form_label">Title</span><input id="mytitle" type="text" value="" name="title" style="width:400px" class="inputText required"></p>
    <p><label>Upload</label><input id="myfile" type="file" name="song">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></p><input type="hidden" value="935" name="page_id">
</form>
```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/fddXt/) for the working JSFiddle. If you've never used jQuery before, then tell me, as this may be confusing!

**Edit:** Here's the replacing code:

```
$('#myfile').change( function(){
    var fileValue = $(this).val();
    fileValue = fileValue.replace('_', ' ');
    fileValue = fileValue.replace('-', ' ');
    $('#mytitle').val(fileValue);
});
```

[Here's the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fddXt/2/)

Comment: i have noticed that if the file name consistes of _ and - it is also being shown in the name ,. is there any way i can replace the _ and - with space

Comment: try: `fileValue = fileValue.replace('_', ' ');` and `fileValue = fileValue.replace('-', ' ');` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the code and a link to a new jsfiddle.

Comment: it works great in mozilla but in google chrome and ie9  it shows full path like c:/mymusic/tyttt.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
//use this in your form tag
<input id="song" type="file" />
//use this in your destination(action)
document.title = document.getElementById("song").value ;
```

Comment: how can i enable auto submit after users has selected the music file

Comment: i have noticed that if the file name consistes of _ and - it is also being shown in the name ,. is there any way i can replace the _ and - with space

Comment: it works great in mozilla but in google chrome and ie9  it shows full path like c:/mymusic/tyttt.mp3